# Problem in adding a title to tcolorbox

Tags: titles, tcolorbox

I have defined a python environment in my document using `tcolorbox`. I would like to add a title to the listing. However, the compiler complains about adding the following to `pythoncode` environment:

```
\begin{pythoncode}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading]
```

When I remove the above options and only use `\begin{pythoncode}[]`, the code compiles successfully. In below is a MWE about this problem.

```
\documentclass{book}    
\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}    

\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx, color}    
\usepackage{hyperref}       
\hypersetup{ %    
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},    
    colorlinks=true,    
}    

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{tcolorbox}    
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable}    


\newtcblisting{pythoncode}[1][]{    
  listing engine=minted,    
  breakable,   
  colback=bg,    
  colframe=black!70,    
  listing only,    
  minted style=colorful,    
  minted language=python,    
  minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},    
  left=5mm,enhanced,    
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)    
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}}    
}    


\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}    

\begin{document}    

\section{Python example}    
\begin{pythoncode}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading]    
# indent your Python code to put into an email    
import glob    
# glob supports Unix style pathname extensions    
python_files = glob.glob('*.py')    
for file_name in sorted(python_files):    
    print '    ------' + file_name    

    with open(file_name) as f:    
        for line in f:    
            print '    ' + line.rstrip()    

    print    
\end{pythoncode}    

\end{document}
```

Could someone shed light on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the argument, `#1`, in the incorrect place; you currently have it here:

```
minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true,#1},
```

so you are passing the options to the `minted` package, which is not what you want to do.

Instead, move it to the end of your options list, just after the `overlay` command:

```
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)    
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
            #1,
```

Here's a working version - note that `hyperref` should be loaded last in this case; see [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before) for more details.

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass{book}    
\usepackage[left=1.00in, right=1.00in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in]{geometry}    

\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{tcolorbox}    
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable}    

\usepackage{hyperref}       
\hypersetup{ %    
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},    
    colorlinks=true,    
}    

\newtcblisting{pythoncode}[1][]{    
  listing engine=minted,    
  breakable,   
  colback=bg,    
  colframe=black!70,    
  listing only,    
  minted style=colorful,    
  minted language=python,    
  minted options={linenos=true,numbersep=3mm,texcl=true},    
  left=5mm,enhanced,    
  overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[black!25] (frame.south west)    
            rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);\end{tcbclipinterior}},
            #1,
}    

\begin{document}    

\section{Python example}    
\begin{pythoncode}[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,title=My nice heading]    
# indent your Python code to put into an email    
import glob    
# glob supports Unix style pathname extensions    
python_files = glob.glob('*.py')    
for file_name in sorted(python_files):    
    print '    ------' + file_name    

    with open(file_name) as f:    
        for line in f:    
            print '    ' + line.rstrip()    

    print    
\end{pythoncode}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ cmhughes: Thanks. But this removes the background color and replaces it with white. Only the line numbers are in defined `bg` color.

Comment: @Ahm I don't understand; you call your environment with `[colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black....` which changes the background colour to `red!5!white` which is nearly white. It does not remove the background color

Comment: @ cmhughes: I am very sorry. You are right. Thank you for your help. How would it be possible to pass one argument to `minted options` and one to `tcolorbox` at the same time?

Comment: @Ahm that depends - do you want them both optional? If so, that could be tricky (without `xparse`)